# Groupby and ffill specified columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I want to sort values by `id_`, `Code`, `Timestamp` (since time order matters), then groupby `d1` using `id_` and `Code`, then forward fill using `ffill` for `NaN` **for each group, on columns `V1` and `V2` only**, while keeping other columns constant, and return the full table.

`d1`:

```
    Type_x  id_             Timestamp               V1   Code Type_y    V2
0   abcd    39-38-30-34     2012-09-20 23:46:05.870 35.5    2    NaN    0
1   abcd    39-38-30-34     2012-09-20 23:46:23.870 44.5    0    NaN    1
2   abcd    39-38-30-34     2012-09-20 23:48:07.870 43.5    0    NaN    1
3   abcd    39-38-30-34     2012-09-20 23:49:48.870 42.5    0    NaN    NaN
4   abcd    39-38-30-34     2012-09-20 23:50:44.870 34.5    2    NaN    NaN
```

Tried:

```
d2 = d1.sort_values(by = ['id_', 'Code', 'Timestamp']).groupby(['id_', 'Code'])['V1', 'V2'].ffill()
```

which only returned two columns:

```
        V1      V2
69659   21.5    NaN
300886  21.5    1.0
300887  21.5    0.0
70086   23.0    0.0
300955  23.0    1.0
```

How should I do it properly?

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: note you may have a typo in the 5th row of your id column: `39-38-30-34-` (dash at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` and do it column by column if you have other columns in your actual dataframe other than the columns you want to `groupby` and the columns you want to `ffill`:

```
d2 = d1.sort_values(by = ['id_', 'Code', 'Timestamp'])
d2['V1'] = d2.groupby(['id_', 'Code'])['V1'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
d2['V2'] = d2.groupby(['id_', 'Code'])['V2'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
d2
Out[1]: 
  Type_x          id_                Timestamp    V1  Code  Type_y   V2
1  abcd   39-38-30-34  2012-09-20 23:46:23.870  44.5  0    NaN      1.0
2  abcd   39-38-30-34  2012-09-20 23:48:07.870  43.5  0    NaN      1.0
3  abcd   39-38-30-34  2012-09-20 23:49:48.870  42.5  0    NaN      1.0
0  abcd   39-38-30-34  2012-09-20 23:46:05.870  35.5  2    NaN      0.0
4  abcd   39-38-30-34  2012-09-20 23:50:44.870  34.5  2    NaN      0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you need returned?

```
d2 = d1.sort_values(by = ['id_', 'Code', 'Timestamp']).groupby(['id_', 'Code']).ffill()

    

             Type_x     Timestamp    V1  Type_y   V2
1 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:46:23.870  44.5     NaN  1.0
2 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:48:07.870  43.5     NaN  1.0
3 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:49:48.870  42.5     NaN  1.0
0 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:46:05.870  35.5     NaN  0.0
4 abcd  39-38-30-34-  23:50:44.870  34.5     NaN  0.0
```

**Or**

```
d2 = d1.sort_values(by = ['id_', 'Code', 'Timestamp']).groupby(['id_', 'Code']).ffill().dropna(1)
print(d2)

 

             Type_x     Timestamp    V1   V2
1 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:46:23.870  44.5  1.0
2 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:48:07.870  43.5  1.0
3 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:49:48.870  42.5  1.0
0 abcd   39-38-30-34  23:46:05.870  35.5  0.0
4 abcd  39-38-30-34-  23:50:44.870  34.5  0.0
```

Comment: @nilsinelabore was this helpful, can look into it if you needed